# What is the correct way to deal with .dat file and to format it in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, format

I am working on a census data received from IPUMS.ORG. The file format is ".dat". 
Some how the following code opened the dat file. But all the data is combined into a single column. I am not sure if this is the best way to deal with it.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('ipumsi_00002.dat')
>>df
 1    250196825019680100000000100000002000000100002000    
 2    2501968250196801000000003000000020000002000020...  
 ... #and thousand of more rows
```

I wonder if there is a way to split each row into numbers with different lengths. Such as

```
     id  year  country  schooling  educ     ...  
 1   250 1968  25019680  100000    00010000 ...
```

Comment: https://stharrold.github.io/20160110-etl-census-with-python.html found by googling **python pandas read census file**

Comment: Maybe the file is white space delimited. You can try. `pd.read_csv('ipumsi_00002.dat', sep='\s+')`